# Is this pCAMBIA co-transformation possible?

Tags: botany, biotechnology

I would like to know whether the pCAMBIA1200 and pCAMBIA0380 be used for co-transformation of rice using Agrobacterium LBA4404.They probably have the same ori site so they belong to the same incompatibility group.So will they co-exist in one Agrobacterium strain and be transferred to the rice plant?

Please let me know.

Comment: It would be good if you include the plasmid map.

Answer (score 1):

[image: pCAMBIA1200]

[image: pCAMBIA0380]

[image: ori site description]

Please check and tell me and how do I go about the co-transformation of rice using Agrobacterium starting from E.coli